# Cart stays empty when i choose product and add them to cart

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

Can't seem to find out why it doesn't show selected products in the cart when I click on the button, my first though was that it doesn't get saved to localStorage, I don't see anything 'cartItems' there but then I couldn't figure out what's wrong with my code..

App.js:

```
import "./App.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import HomeScreen from "./components/screens/HomeScreen";
import ProductScreen from "./components/screens/ProductScreen";
import CartScreen from "./components/screens/CartSreen";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="my-3">
        <Container>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductScreen />} />
            <Route path="/cart/:id" element={<CartScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        </Container>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

ProductScreen.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Image,
  ListGroup,
  Button,
  Card,
  Form,
} from "react-bootstrap";
//import products from "../../products";
import Rating from "../Rating";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Message from "../Message";
import Loader from "../Loader";
import { listProductDetails } from "../../actions/ProductAction";
import { productDetailsReducers } from "../../reducers/ProductReducers";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function ProductScreen() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const { id } = useParams();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { loading, error, product } = productDetails;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProduct() {
      if (id) {
        dispatch(listProductDetails(id));
      }
    }
    fetchProduct();
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  const addToCartHandler = () => {
    if (id) {
      navigate(`/cart/${id}?quantity=${quantity}`);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Link to="/" className="btn btn-dark my-3">
        Go Back
      </Link>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : error ? (
        <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          <Col md={6}>
            <Image
              className="imgCustom"
              src={product.image}
              alt={product.name}
            ></Image>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h3>{product.name}</h3>
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Rating
                  value={product.rating}
                  text={`${product.numReviews} reviews`}
                  color={"f8e825"}
                />
              </ListGroup.Item>
              <ListGroup.Item>Price : ${product.price}</ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                Description: ${product.description}
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Col>

          <Col md={3}>
            <Card>
              <ListGroup variant="flush">
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Price : </Col>
                    <Col>
                      <strong>$ {product.price}</strong>
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>

                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Row>
                    <Col>Status : </Col>
                    <Col>
                      {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock" : "Out of Stock"}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                {product.countInStock > 0 && (
                  <ListGroup.Item>
                    <Row>
                      <Col>Qty</Col>
                      <Col xs="auto" className="my-1">
                        <Form.Control
                          as="select"
                          value={quantity}
                          onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
                        >
                          {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                              {x + 1}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </Form.Control>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                )}
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <Button
                    className="btn-block"
                    disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                    type="button"
                    onClick={addToCartHandler}
                  >
                    Add to Cart
                  </Button>
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductScreen;
```

CartScreen.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Image,
  ListGroup,
  Button,
  Card,
  Form,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Message from "../Message";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "../../actions/CartActions";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function CartSreen() {
  let location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { productId } = useParams();
  const quantity = location.search ? Number(location.search.split("=")[1]) : 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const { cartItems } = cart;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, quantity));
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, quantity]);

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id));
  };

  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    navigate("/login?redirect=shipping");
  };
  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={8}>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
          <Message variant="info">
            Your cart is empty <Link to="/">Go Back</Link>
          </Message>
        ) : (
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            {cartItems.map((item) => (
              <ListGroup.Item key={item.product}>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>${item.price}</Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Form.Control
                      as="select"
                      value={item.quantity}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={1}>
                    <Button
                      type="button"
                      variant="light"
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        )}
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}>
        <Card>
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>
                Subtotal (
                {cartItems.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity, 0)}) items
              </h2>
              $
              {cartItems
                .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.quantity * item.price, 0)
                .toFixed(2)}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
          <ListGroup.Item>
            <Button
              type="button"
              className="btn-block"
              disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
              onClick={checkoutHandler}
            >
              Proceed to Checkout
            </Button>
          </ListGroup.Item>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
}

export default CartSreen;
```

CartReducers.js:

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM } from "../constants/CartConstants";

export const cartReducer = (state = { cartItems: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CART_ADD_ITEM:
      const item = action.payload;
      const existItem = state.cartItems.find((x) => x.product === item.product);
      if (existItem) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.map((x) =>
            x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
          ),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
        };
      }
    case CART_REMOVE_ITEM:
      return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product !== action.payload),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

CartAction.js:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM } from "../constants/CartConstants";

export const addToCart = (id, quantity) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`);

  dispatch({
    type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
    payload: {
      product: data._id,
      name: data.name,
      image: data.image,
      price: data.price,
      countInStock: data.countInStock,
      quantity,
    },
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};

export const removeFromCart = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({
    type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
    payload: id,
  });
  localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems));
};
```

Store.js:

```
import {
  legacy_createStore as createStore,
  combineReducers,
  applyMiddleware,
} from "redux";
//import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import {
  productListReducers,
  productDetailsReducers,
} from "./reducers/ProductReducers";
import { cartReducer } from "./reducers/CartReducers";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  productList: productListReducers,
  productDetails: productDetailsReducers,
  cart: cartReducer,
});

const cartItemsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem("cartItems")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems"))
  : [];

const initialState = {
  cart: { cartItems: cartItemsFromStorage },
};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

Comment: Show your router config as well

Comment: By the way, your current design allows malicious users to send someone a link that would automatically add a product to their cart

Comment: Done, oh and how can i fix that? @KonradLinkowski

Comment: I would add a product to cart at the `ProductScreen` and then navigate to the `CartScreen`. Because now If someone clicks a link like `yousite.com/cart/3123?quantity=120100` will have products added to the cart

Comment: You've declared your param as `:id` but you are trying to get `productId`, it has to be the same. Either change it in router or here `const { id } = useParams();`

Comment: I still haven't implemented protected routes if that's the solution, any idea about why i can't add items to cart and display their quantity and price? @KonradLinkowski

Comment: Because of the `id` `productId` mismatch

Comment: YES! that was the issue, thank you! And with security protected routes would suffice? @KonradLinkowski

Comment: I don't know what kind of protection would help here